# cordova 3 and fullPath

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

In previous versions of cordova/phonegap the URL returned by fullPath and toURL() on a file or directory returned (in Android) "file:///mnt/sdcard".

```
window.requestFileSystem(
    LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,
    0,
    function(fs){
        console.log(fs.root.fullPath);
        console.log(fs.root.toURL());
    },
    function(error){
        console.error('Failed to get file system:' + error);
    }
);
```

The above code using cordova 3.3.1-0.4.2 is returning:

```
02-20 15:56:56.746 I/Web Console(27239): / at file:///android_asset/www/js/ui.js:64
02-20 15:56:56.746 I/Web Console(27239): cdvfile://localhost/persistent/ at file:///android_asset/www/js/ui.js:65
```

This is fine for using cordova based functionality but if I want to pass a URL to a third party library, the URL is meaningless. (My example is I have a GPX file stored locally and I need to pass the location to an openlayers layer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new cdvfile protocol does not work in android 2, for this reason the method toNativeURL() has been added to 1.0.1 of the org.apache.cordova.file plugin, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6106.

Answer (score 0):

actually not linked with the version of cordova but the version of the  plugins. Have you looked at [the release notes of the new version of the plugins](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/02/10/plugins-release.html)?

(I must admit it's not really clear for me either for the moment)

Raymond Camden made [a blog entry on the subject](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2014/2/17/Cordova-File-System--Important-Update), maybe can you ask question [there](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2014/2/17/Cordova-File-System--Important-Update)?